# How to use Sympy symbolically solve equation using the only variable I design

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Given equation

```
x + y + z = 1
y = x
```

Then we can expression

```
z = 1 - 2x
```

And also this is valid as well

```
z = 1 - 2y
```

I hope to write this two equations in Sympy and **z** is only expressed in **x**.

I know I can get this done by adding **y** as an unknown as well.

I just **don't want to use that because I have equations got too many redundant variable that I don't want to write ALL of those variable as output**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `exclude` flag to tell it what variable(s) to not solve for (and to treat as a constant):

```
>>> solve(eqns, exclude=[x])
{y: x, z: -2*x + 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do substitutions to eliminate 'redundant' variables:

```
e1 = Eq(x + y + z, 1)
e1.subs(y, x)

2x + z = 1 # sympy live scraped pretty print output
```